# Qt QML GridLayout cell text alignment error

Tags: qt, qml

I'm build a simple `GridLayout` to undestand cell text alignment using Qt QML.

Code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    id: rootWindow

    visible: true
    height: 400
    width: 640

    Rectangle {
        id: headerBackground
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "orange"

        GridLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 2

            columns: 3
            rows: 1

            columnSpacing: 0
            rowSpacing: 0

            Rectangle {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft || Qt.AlignVCenter
                color: "blue"

                Text {
                    color: "white"
                    font.family: "Inter"
                    font.pointSize: 14
                    font.bold: true
                    text: "LEFT"
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter || Qt.AlignVCenter
                color: "red"

                Text {
                    color: "white"
                    font.family: "Inter"
                    font.pointSize: 14
                    font.bold: true
                    text: "CENTER"
                }
            }

            Rectangle {
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight || Qt.AlignVCenter
                color: "green"

                Text {
                    color: "white"
                    font.family: "Inter"
                    font.pointSize: 14
                    font.bold: true
                    text: "RIGHT"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I expect all 3 texts to be vertically centered.

Horizontally alignment I expect the `LEFT` text aligned left, the `CENTER` text aligned in the center and the `RIGHT` text aligned in the right side.

Here is what I'm getting - all texts are being horizontally aligned in the left and vertically aligned in the top:

[image]

I came from CSS/HTML `flex` world and I'm sure I'm missing how QML Layout works. How can I make this simple example work?

Comment: The alignment is relative to the parent and you are only aligning the rectangles, not the texts. By default the elements are not aligned but at the position (0,0) with respect to the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you must align the `Text`, not the `Rectangle`.
The `Rectangle` fill all the space, thanks to:

```
Rectangle {
    Layout.fillHeight: true
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    // ...
}
```

Next, the `Text` have to be aligned inside the rectangle, you have to specify the size of your text area:

```
Text {
    anchors.fill: parent
    // ...
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
}
```

Full code:

```
Rectangle {
    id: headerBackground
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "orange"

    GridLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 2

        columns: 3
        rows: 1

        columnSpacing: 0
        rowSpacing: 0

        // Left
        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            color: "blue"

            Text {
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: "white"
                font.family: "Inter"
                font.pointSize: 14
                font.bold: true
                text: "LEFT"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            }
        }

        // Center
        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            color: "red"

            Text {
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: "white"
                font.family: "Inter"
                font.pointSize: 14
                font.bold: true
                text: "CENTER"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            }
        }

        // Right
        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            color: "green"

            Text {
                anchors.fill: parent
                color: "white"
                font.family: "Inter"
                font.pointSize: 14
                font.bold: true
                text: "RIGHT"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignRight
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            }
        }
    }
}
```